# put the contact list of account to the cc field in email

Tags: email, plugins, dynamics-crm-4

i have a mission to make a plug-in in crm 4 which should 1. put in the subject field of an email the name of the account and then 2. put the contact list of account to the cc field of the email.
the first thing i did and it work, but the second... not so much...
i have seen some samples but none of them was close to halp me... 
i would like to have help and explain of how to find the list of the contact that belong to the account and then put the list in the cc field.
here is the begining...:

```
namespace mail
{
public class Class1 : IPlugin
{
        public void Execute(IPluginExecutionContext context)
        {
            DynamicEntity entity = null;

            if (context.InputParameters.Properties.Contains("Target") &&
               context.InputParameters.Properties["Target"] is DynamicEntity)
            {
                entity = (DynamicEntity)context.InputParameters.Properties["Target"];

                if (entity.Name != EntityName.account.ToString())
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                // updating the subject of the email
                ICrmService service = context.CreateCrmService(true);
                account accountRecord = (account)service.Retrieve("account", ((Key)entity.Properties["accountid"]).Value, new ColumnSet(new string[] { "name" }));
                String str = String.Empty;
                str = accountRecord.name.ToString();
                DynamicEntity followup = new DynamicEntity();
                followup.Name = EntityName.email.ToString();

                followup.Properties = new PropertyCollection();
                followup.Properties.Add(new StringProperty("subject", str));

                //updating the CC of the email

                TargetCreateDynamic targetCreate = new TargetCreateDynamic();
                targetCreate.Entity = followup;

                CreateRequest create = new CreateRequest();
                create.Target = targetCreate;

                CreateResponse created = (CreateResponse)service.Execute(create);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(
                      "An error occurred in the AccountUpdateHandler plug-in.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
List<BusinessEntity> contactList = GetNeededContacts(crmService, sourceEntity);
email targetEmail = GetTargetEmail(crmService, emailid);            
foreach (DynamicEntity contact in contactList)
            {
                activityparty contActParty = new activityparty() { partyid = new Lookup("contact", contact.contactid.Value };
                List<activityparty> tmpList = targetEmail.cc.ToList();
                tmpList.Add(contActParty);
                targetEmail.cc = tmpList.ToArray();
            }
crmService.Update(targetEmail);
```

You only have to develop the function to get the contact, user or account references.